# How to make objective agreement measurable for project work

Tags: project-management, projects, employment-agreement

So I got this new job, which is my first completely project-based job.

My salary is partially bound to an objective agreement. This agreement has to be done. My Manager gave me his proposal to this agreement, but I'm not happy with it because it isn't measurable.

As I don't have any firm education towards project management, I don't know any method to work out a measurable project-based agreement.

What methods exist, to make projects measurable which aren't 100% planable?
(For example: As a worker in a project, I can't guarantee the whole project will be a success since there are too many factors which I can't affect)

What are well known traps which I should avoid?

Comment: What does *bound to an objective agreement* mean? Your second paragraph is unclear to me. Is this something from your country?

Comment: It has nothing to do with local law, i would be astonished if this where an special thing in my country. 
With "bound to an objective agreement" I mean, that there is a part of my salary which I will  only receive, if the objective agreement is fulfilled. Some kind of bonus.

Comment: I will point out that as far as getting a bonus is concerned, you are usually far better off with a subjective measurement than an objective one. That way, the person making the measurement can allow for things outside your control that affect project success.  Often that is not the case with an objective measure.  I remember one time I succeeded at none of my objective measures because I got assigned something totally different, that was way above my paygrade, mission critical and and wildly successful. But I couldn't get a performance bonus because I didn't meet the objective criteria.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably too widen but i'll try at least to answer to the following :

> What methods exist, to make projects measurable which aren't 100%
>   planable? (For example: As a worker in a project, I can't guarantee
>   it's success due there are too many factory which I can't affect)

Basically when it comes to planning, you always associate a risk factor along with the planned time it will take, depends on the risks, you will affect X hours to get it finished but will in fact plan Y hours, Y > X, the more risky the more Y will grow. Basically you need experience to adjust Y properly and to get to know your team.

> What well known traps exists which I should avoid?

I will answer we're talking about IT development here to make my point, though a good part of what I will say is surely true anywhere.

1. If you are only a project manager without technical skills (or not enough), trust your team when they give you numbers (factor risk/time). Even though I'm quite young, I already saw too many lost of profits because the projects manager was shortening the time that the developers evaluates for a functonnality to implements.
2. Don't underestimate the risk factor, if you or your team need some hints about that, google 'agile risk factor'. Even if you don't go with agile methods, what is said about this is still true.
3. Having good quality measurements is hard, it comes mainly to experience and know your team. I can only give you that one in IT field as a sample : *number of line of code is the **worst** way of measuring performance*.
4. As the project manager, you're the entry point of the team, no one should be allow to take time of your people without you knowing it, so you can replan the tasks.

Finally :

1. Google about *Gant diagramm* and check the [critical path method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_path_method). The first is about to visualize your planning, the second is about how to dispatch some task and identify among the different paths the critic one (the one that will delay everything). I think it's the very basic of project managing.
2. Read books about 1- project management, 2- quality, 3-communication/leadership reading about the ISO 9001 is good too.

Comment: I'd also add something about SERVQUAL and the GAP-model.

Comment: @Migz you can suggest an edit or post your answer as complement. I don't know them (I've been formed to the basics of project management but I'm a simple dev :p)

Comment: I just realized there are billions of things to add to the list. I just also thought of the "Prince2" way of working (projects in controlled enviroments). Then there's the waterfall method, agile methods like scrum, etc. In the end, I feel like the question itself is simply too broad :)

Comment: yes this is why I recommend to go for the books. I still though some hints would benefits to OP

Answer (score 1):

> What methods exist, to make projects measurable which aren't 100%
>   planable?

Find some basically independent source to judge the achievement of the objective.

For example, "project success" could be judge by the sales increase achieve due to the completion of the project, or by a customer satisfaction survey, etc.

Many objective have factors outside your direct control. Unfortunately, that the way things work.

Work with your Manager to come up with an approach to judging completion of your objective that you can both agree with.